# how could i get the sound's volume get down slowly?

Tags: java, audio, midi, volume, fadeout

i can play a sound, like this:

```
channel.noteOn(noteNumber, velocity);
```

and i stop the sound, like this:

```
channel.noteOff(noteNumber);
```

but the soundoff should stop, when the volume is 0, so like: the sound is playing 2000ms, and than the sound's volume will get down in 1000ms (after 1000ms the volume will be 0), and than the sound will stop
i found this code:

```
channel.noteOff(noteNumber, velocity);
```

but it doesn't do any volumedown effekt.
please help me!!
thanks

Comment: You might want to use the term "fade out" there. It'll be a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this.

The first (and recommended) method is to tweak the envlope:  Set the [release time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADSR_envelope#ADSR_envelope) using `CC72`.  With *most* synths, you can adjust this parameter to choose how long that note will fade out post release.

The second method is to simply lower the volume of the channel using `CC7`.

Which method you pick depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Using velocity in Note Off only has an effect if the patch is programmed to respond to note off velocity. I'm not sure how programmable your system is, but you could potentially have note off velocity affect the Release time of the amplitude envelope.

If that's not an option, experiment with Volume (controller 7) and Expression (controller 11). The trade-off there is that they affect every note on that channel.

Comment: I haven't used Java in almost ten years so I don't know the syntax you'd use, but you'd send a controller event with controller 7 or 11 and a value from 0 (silent) to 127 (maximum volume). They will affect all notes playing on that channel. If you want a smooth change, you'll need to set up a timer to send multiple commands with decreasing values.

Answer (score -1):

Check [the JavaDoc for that method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/MidiChannel.html#noteOff%28int,%20int%29). It states that the effect can depend on the used instrument. So you might want to experiment with different instruments and see what happens there.

Anyway, I think method [setPolyPressure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/MidiChannel.html#setPolyPressure%28int,%20int%29) could be more what you're looking for. However, to implement a smooth fade-out, you'd need to call the method multiple times with decreasing pressure. That'd require the use of a `Timer` or some other asynchronous utility. Seems a bit awkward, but I'm just not seeing anything directly usable in the whole Java midi interface.

Comment: i see: "...is typically used to vary such features as the VOLUME...",
but i can't do it, i write this code: channel.setPolyPressure(noteNumber,100), but nothing changes :(
i wrote it before the channel.noteon.. code, and after that, but doesn't work :( how???? :(

Comment: @victorio I'm not all that familiar with MIDI but I'll play around with this a bit later today. See if I can get a fade going. In the meantime, SSteve's answer corresponds to what's suggested on the official MIDI spec site, so see what you can do with that.

Comment: Poly aftertouch (pressure) has nothing to do with this.